# Google Chart resize with parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-visualization

I am having a little issue.  I make a call to my database and return some data.  I then pass this response to my Google chart function

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/process.php",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(response) {

        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() { drawChart(response); });

    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        return false;
    });
});
```

This all works fine.  The problem is making it responsive.  According to what I have seen online, to do this, I can just add a resize function

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    drawChart();
});
```

However, this will not have the data from my response.  What is the best way to get the data from my Ajax request to the resize function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

first, google's `load` statement will wait for the page to load by default.
which can be used in place of --> `$(function () {});`, `$(document).ready`, etc...
it only needs to be called once per page load, so call it first.

then you can use the following setup...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/process.php",
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(response) {

    drawChart(response);
    $(window).resize(function(){
      drawChart(response);
    });

  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      return false;
  });

});
```

note: you can use the promise the `load` statement returns,
in place of --> `setOnLoadCallback`